# To display a msg untill an act progress is going on and tp stop displaying the msg once the activity is completed without closing the dlg

Tags: java, progress-bar, progressdialog

I want an activity to happen . So when its started , it opens a dialog showing *please wait* and also the progress of the activity in the same dialog . Once the activity is completed , I want that please wait option to vanish (stop displaying). How can this be done ?

```
progressDialog.setIntroMessage("<HTML>" + theIntroMsg + " ..." + "<BR><BR>Please wait...</HTML>");
progressDialog.setVisible(true);
progressDialog.taskStart();
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible, you should try to use a `ProgressMonitorDialog`.

```
ProgressMonitorDialog progress = new ProgressMonitorDialog(null);
try {
    progress.run(false, true, new IRunnableWithProgress() {
        @Override
        public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
            monitor.beginTask("Please wait...", IProgressMonitor.UNKNOWN);
            try {
                //do something
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                monitor.done();
            }
    }
});
```